# How to set data dynamically in NSTableView mac?

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I am trying to create an NSTableView with dynamic content, rows and columns.
And I am creating columns dynamically with the data array like

```
private func addHeader() {
    self.dbTableView.tableColumns.forEach { self.dbTableView.removeTableColumn($0)}
    for  column in table!.columnNames {
        let tableColumn = NSTableColumn()
        tableColumn.headerCell.title = column
        tableColumn.headerCell.alignment = .center
        tableColumn.identifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: column)

        self.dbTableView.addTableColumn(tableColumn)
    }
}
```

And I have override the delegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    guard let vw = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else { return nil }

    for i in 0..<table!.columnCount {
        let columnName = table?.columnNames[i]
        let data = table?.rows[row][i]

        if tableColumn!.identifier.rawValue == columnName {
            vw.textField?.stringValue = data ?? ""
        }
    }
    return vw
}
```

But the `makeView(withIdentifier:, owner:)` returns `nil` always.

I have tried below delegate but it did not fire.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    for i in 0..<table!.columnCount {
        let columnName = table?.columnNames[i]
        let data = table?.rows[row][i]

        if tableColumn!.identifier.rawValue == columnName {
            return data
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please read the documentation of `makeView(withIdentifier:owner:)`. `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)` is a `NSTableViewDataSource` method.

Comment: If your datasource class implements `viewForTableColumn` then `objectValueForTableColumn` would not be used(called) by `NSTableVIew`.

Comment: Your tableView did'nt registered the nib to create a view when `makeViewWithIdentifier` is called. Register a nib with the identifier and it will not return nil.

Comment: @BharatKumar `objectValueForTableColumn` is called when `viewForTableColumn` is implemented.